# Gráfica de barras usando Dash, Pandas y Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, dash

Estoy haciendo una gráfica de barras usando dash, pandas y plotly en python, pero al terminar el código me muestra la gráfica pero sin información. Al revisar me doy cuenta que los datos de las columnas son de tipo str, cómo hago para que me cuente los datos?

'''

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_excel('DH.xlsx')

fig = px.bar(df, x="Tratamiento", y="Ambiente",hover_name="Agente")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

'''

[image: Resultado de la Gráfica]

Answer (score 0):

Con Pandas puedes pasar las columnas al tipo de datos que desees usando el método `.astype()`. Te quedo como cambiaría tu código.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_excel('DH.xlsx')

#Aquí lo pasamos a float, tu puedes poner cualquier tipo de dato.
df['Tratamiento'] = df['Tratamiento].astype(float)
df['Ambiente] = df['Ambiente'].astype(float)

fig = px.bar(df, x="Tratamiento", y="Ambiente",hover_name="Agente")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

En el caso de que el **hover** se base en un tipo de dato distinto y sea el que te esté dando problemas, también puedes cambiarlo con el mísmo método.